# Keeping user logged on, on Android an android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, authentication, ksoap2

Hey guys i am currently working on an android app that will allow me to login with a registered user and then post how much he heighs, his collesterol level and so on, trough web services using ksoap, and i don't know how to keep the user logged on trough a web service like ksoap for then to introduce the values. I don't have code yet i am just trying to figure out how am i going to do it, because in android i guess you could say i am still taking baby steps. The website where the info will be posted is already created but i need to know how i keep the user logged in so that then i can put his numbers and send trough the web services to the site db the right values to the right user.

Comment: We need more info about the sites you will be calling with soap. SOAP supports authentication, so it can be possible to add the login/password to the headers. The website behind can then check your credentials

Comment: Yes but to check it it needs a web service that will do it, i have seen in other posts people saying to use sharedpreferences,a and it seemed like a good idea but i don't know how to use them in this situation so that when i send the values it invoques the values on the shared preferences and posts the info in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , you can save `boolean variable in Shared Preference` when user `logged in` . So when ever you want to send data you need to check the value of that `boolean variable` . if its true then you can send data otherwise redirect to login page.

When user logged out then you need to set false to that variable in shared preference or clear shared preference.

**Example**

```
public class PreferenceData 
{
    static final String PREF_USER_ID = "user_logged_in";

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) 
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserLoggedIn(Context ctx, boolean userLoggedIn) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_USER_ID, userLoggedIn);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static boolean getUserLoggedIn(Context ctx) 
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).putBoolean(PREF_USER_ID, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag great help for now. Can you give your e-mail if in the future i have problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

well, you can save a token with a timestamp in the sqlite db or flash memory and send it as a parameter in your request. when you check if the login token exists, you can check towards timestamp if you want it to time out - create a logout function that clears this token

Comment: i am interning and they want something simple they don't want me to use db on my side since i working trough the client side